# Switch expression in SSRS

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services

I wanted to fill cell based on value. First expression works only for LimeGreen, but IIF for all cases. Why?

```
=Switch(
Code.Trend(Variables!Sold1.Value, Variables!Sold2.Value) > 0, "LimeGreen",
Code.Trend(Variables!Sold1.Value, Variables!Sold2.Value) <= 0 &
Code.Trend(Variables!Sold1.Value, Variables!Sold2.Value) >= -0.05, "Yellow",
Code.Trend(Variables!Sold1.Value, Variables!Sold2.Value) < -0.05, "Red")

=IIF(
Code.Trend(Variables!Sold1.Value, Variables!Sold2.Value) > 0, "LimeGreen",
    IIF(Code.Trend(Variables!Sold1.Value, Variables!Sold2.Value) < 0.05, "Red", "Yellow")
)
```

Comment: Are you sure symbol `&` = `And`? I think it's used for string concatenation

Comment: You are right. I deleted second condition and put Yellow as other.

Comment: What does Code.Trend() return?

Comment: FYI: Switch breaks out at the first true condition so you can simplify your statement. `=Switch(
Code.Trend(Variables!Sold1.Value, Variables!Sold2.Value) > 0, "LimeGreen",
Code.Trend(Variables!Sold1.Value, Variables!Sold2.Value) >= -0.05, "Yellow",
True, "Red")`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
=Switch(
Code.Trend(Variables!Sold1.Value, Variables!Sold2.Value) > 0, "LimeGreen",
Code.Trend(Variables!Sold1.Value, Variables!Sold2.Value) >= -0.05, "Yellow",
True, "Red")
```

Anything above 0 will be LimeGreen.  After that, anything above -.05 will be Yellow.  Everything else will be Red.

Since the first test looks for >0, the remainining options are all <= 0.  This effectively means the second test is all values between -.05 and 0.  The final test is the catch all but will only be chosen for values <-.05.